# javascript add background audio to game

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, game-development

I am attempting to add a mp3 file to my game menu, but I cannot get it to play unless I use controls and physically have to press the play button on the browser next to the game canvas.

I have been to several websites and tutorials, as I know this is a common question, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

So far I have tried adding

```
const audioObj = new Audio("/assets/menuTheme.mp3");

audioObj.play();
```

to my game.js file in the update function, but that didn't work.

I have added the  to my html file in multiple ways such as:

```
<audio id= 'menuAudio'>
<source src='/assets/menuTheme.mp3'>
</audio>
```

and

```
<audio controls autoplay loop>
<source id = 'menuAudio' src='/assets/menuTheme.mp3'/>
<embed src= '/assets/menuTheme.mp3' autoplay='autoplay' loop='loop'/>
</audio>
```

then calling it in my game.js file by

```
this.sound = document.getElementById('menuAudio');
this.sound.play();
```

I even found one answer to create a function or a class for the sound

```
sound = function(src) {
this.sound = document.createElement('audio');
this.sound.src = src;
this.sound.setAttribute('preload', 'auto');
this.sound.setAttribute('controls', 'none');
this.sound.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(this.sound);
this.play = function() {
    this.sound.play();
}
this.stop = function() {
    this.sound.pause();
}
}
```

Nothing has worked, and I am stumped on what else to do. I know the file is supported by the browser I am using and is uploaded properly, because it will play, just not automatically, and not without having the control panel showing.

Please help :)

SOLVED:

always check if auto-play is enabled in the browser...* face-to-palm *

Comment: Do you have autoplay disabled in your browser?

Comment: Oh my goodness, that's embarrassing. It works now. Well I'm glad that it wasn't an error with the file at least. Thanks Robert.

Comment: Robert, do you have any suggestions on how to format the audio so that it doesn't slow down the game? My game is freezing up after about 30 seconds with the audio running.

Comment: It's a different question, but I don't see a reason why the game should slow down when an audio file is played at the same time. Should be independent from each other.

Answer (score 1):

check if the audio is paused first, then play it if it returns true.. also this must happened inside a window.onload event

```
if(audio.isPaused)
   audio.play()
```